# Oracle JDBC Types Mapped to Java Object Types by getObject() - wrong document?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

this is the document link: ["Mapping SQL and Java Types"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html)

let's see  8.9.3 JDBC Types Mapped to Java Object Types
at row: TIMESTAMP - java.sql.Timestamp

but when I use getObject() with oracle database on a TIMESTAMP column, the return type is oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP, it can not been cast to java.sql.Timestamp

I know that I can use getTimestamp() but I need getObject() for handling any resultset regardless of types.

Is the document wrong or me?

Comment: http://alberlau.blogspot.ru/2008/01/oracle-jdbc-oraclesqltimestamp-issue.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document is correct, the Oracle JDBC driver is the problem.

There's 2 possible solutions:

First one, use getObject:

```
oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP ts = (oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP) res.getObject("last_update");
agent.setLastUpdate(new Date(ts.dateValue().getTime()));
```

The second is to add a VM argument to your app:

```
-Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true
```

This will make the driver return `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP`.